# IKEv2 client authentication in tunnel RA vpn

Tags: cisco-anyconnect

When we where using Cisco VPN client, we configured preshared key, under tunnel configuration, and that preshared key had to be configured on VPN client, and on ASA. And client had to have this preshared key if he wanted to connect to ASA. Is preshared key configurable in IKEv2 when tunnel is RA? If not, how can be configured client authentication in tunnel? Not only ASA authentication with certificate that IKEv2 uses.

Comment: Are you asking about site to site or vpn remote access for example anyconnect?

Comment: Remote access (RA) vpn...client authentication in tunnel...but with IKEv2...yes, anyconnect

Comment: for RA I would hook up it to directory like tacacs, LDAP, Radius, or AD. So users can authenticate against directory.

Comment: In IKEv2 tunnel configuration? Do you have CLI example maybe?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to setup directory like Radius to authenticate against.
Please see guide hope that help: [guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/117641-config-asa-00.html)

Although you can have a local users as per this guide: [guide](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/74111/asa-anyconnect-ikev2-configuration-example)

Comment: @datagramnetwork it's better if you quote (or summarize) the information instead of just providing a link.  That way, when links eventually go stale, the helpful information is still here.